# Sorting of uppercase and lowercase strings

Tags: arrays, string, perl

I am trying to **sort uppercase and lowercase strings** in perl in **alphabetical order**. However, for some reason perl **first sorts the uppercase strings and then the lowercase strings** (see example below).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = ("abc","def","PQR","STW");
@array = sort @array;

foreach (@array){
    print "$_ \n";
}
```

Output:

```
PQR 
STW 
abc 
def
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need case insensitive sorting, accomplished by explicitly specifying the sorting criterion

```
my @sorted = sort { "\L$a" cmp "\L$b" } @array;
```

or, better

```
use feature qw(fc);
my @sorted = sort { fc($a) cmp fc($b) } @array;
```

The [`fc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fc.html) is specifically made for this. Also see it in [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html), under *Examples*.

Comment: The fc is faster than the comparison of lowercase strings. The reason for this might be that string conversion is avoided.

Comment: @scs Doesn't surprise. (Did you benchmark it?) It is an internal method used to implement those escapes.  It's probably optimized a lot, and it may actually not copy data. It's the right way to do this.  Note, the `feature` doesn't have to be loaded if there is `use v5.16;` or higher in place.

Comment: Use v5.17 or higher. v5.16 crashes. I did a quick (lazy) benchmarking that alternates normal sort and the different sort algorithms of the answers in a loop. The fc was the fastest algorithm. Better benchmarking would require creating a large array and run the sorting algorithms on it.

Comment: @scs Nice, thanks for info. The crashing ... I have v5.16.3 here, it's fine. Go figure.

Comment: The error is "Undefined subroutine &main::fc called at ../sorttest.pl line 33.". To reproduce the error, it is necessary to first delete the use v.5.16, run perl and then add it again. It then crashes and stops crashing if use v5.16 is replaced by use v5.17. I have perl v5.18.

Comment: @scs `use 5.16;` works perfect for me; I also have 5.18. What you tell sounds as if Perl has a memory between the invocations. I'm sure I misunderstood you ;-)

Comment: @scs It sounds like you nailed a bug there, in your build of v5.16.

Answer (score 1):

you can set your sorting criteria by converting to lowercase of uppercase.

```
@array = sort { lc($a) cmp lc($b) } @array;
```

Comment: Be wary of `lc` when comparing different character sets, as some international variants do slightly strange things.